# Double charged for serial voting - What do I do?

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting, voting-correction

So I had a user that upvoted a bunch of my answers for gratitude. I understand that these points needs to be reversed, since it doesn't look like the user actually paid attention of the content in these answers.

I received an email and I responded to it, the reputation was gone and I thought it would be done. But 8 days later I was charged again and I don't know why. I have already written two emails but no one responded. So I would like to know how to handle this situation?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You were involved in a voting fraud with two other accounts. There was cross-voting between you and these other two accounts. Given that the votes were cast all at once, they were deemed invalid and removed. All parties involved were informed about it in an email. However, the invalidation happened in two phases because it had to be done manually. That's why you see two invalidations a week apart.

Comment: When did the other incident happen? Cause I do not remember any time to get 200 reps, except for this day.

Comment: I believe it was July 10th

Comment: There was a reputation gain of 125 and you charged 200. However, why should it be the case of serial voting? I had similar rep gain before aug 8 for example.

Comment: The way invalidations work is that we escalate issues like this to Community Managers (staff). They recheck the votes and if they believe the votes were targeted, they invalidate ALL votes between the two accounts. It's possible that this user voted for your posts on other days too, but because staff had to invalidate this serial voting, all votes were removed.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: This does not seem fair to me, at least in this *second* incident the user seemed to paid attention to the content. I recently did go through another users answers and upvoted a bunch of answers by this user, because they helped me. However, at least I got a reason why. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: "upvoted a bunch of answers by this user, because they helped me."--Yeah, don't do that.

Comment: @khelwood I should not upvote answers that I find useful ? You seem to misunderstand my comment. Why shouldn't I go through the answers of an user that seems to have some good answers to a technology I am interested in. In addition why should I need to care about *HOW* I vote to whom. I don't get the system, but its only about virtual points.

Comment: “I should not upvote answers that I find useful?” - Targeted voting isn’t allowed and is considered voting fraud. Any reputation earned that is not legitimate is subject to be reversed. Just keep in mind “cross-voting between you and these other two accounts” makes any of those votes invalid

Comment: @Thingamabobs Try to put yourself in our shoes. If we see a lot of votes coming from one account to another, what do you reckon we will think? If a post helped you, feel free to upvote, but try to avoid finding contributions from the same user to upvote.

Comment: @Dharman there is no intention to get *paid* in return. As I understand, upvoting is to signal that it is a useful answer, and the search function let me search for a user with a tag. [so] allows me to go through the answers of a user. I feel like it is intentional that one can find more useful answers of a user. In my point of view, a mistake happened an no one is willing to admit it.

Comment: @SecurityHound It is true, I upvoted some of the questions of that user, cause he could not join me in a chat. The first incident is not on the table for me, there was clearly something wrong in the votings I and the user did. I don't complain about it. The second incident is what bothers me a bit, cause I don't see what is wrong here. But again.. it is about virtual points, no hard feelings here.

Comment: @Thingamabobs We sincerely hope that it was a misunderstanding. I was only trying to explain how to avoid incidents like this in the future. Maybe the staff didn't need to remove these votes, but we don't know what exactly made them do it. They can see individual votes and who voted where and when. Neither you nor the moderators can do that. It's only a couple of upvotes.

Comment: @Dharman agree, case closed. Thanks for your time.